# How to deploy Angular 4 App in Tomcat Server

Tags: angular, tomcat

How can I deploy my Angular 4 application in Tomcat server ? How to create the deployment file for Tomcat ?

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I did it:
- I created a "angular" folder in `tomcat/webapps`
- All of the files from my Angular build (in the `dist` folder) get copied over to that folder 
- Then I add a `WEB-INF/web.xml` in `tomcat/webapps/angular`, which has the following contents:

```
<web-app>
    <error-page>
         <error-code>404</error-code>
         <location>/index.html</location>
     </error-page>
</web-app>
```

That way Tomcat redirects to `index.html` every time a URL is not found, which then leads Angular to handle it with the component router.

Answer (score 1):

You can deploy an angular application into tomcat as war.
Our code repository is on bitbucket cloud, back-end applications were written in java and front-ends were angularjs.

Bitbucket pipeline is very simple tools that you can config it for continuous delivery.

I had prepared a pipeline file to deploy our applications into tomcat  on aws from bitbucket code repository.

I had searched nodejs commandline tools to make it easly.Respectively , following tools guided me to deploy our angular application folder to tomcat.

- npm install -g bestzip
- npm install -g tomcat-deploy
- npm install -g minimist

First operation was prepare war file from app and bower folder.

- bestzip webApplication.war app/ bower_components/

Second operation was undeploy existing web appication.

- tomcat-deploy undeploy --hostname www.example.com --port 80 --login tomcatUser --password tomcatPassword --path /webApplication

Third operation was deploy war file to tomcat.

- tomcat-deploy deploy webApplication.war --hostname www.example.com --port 80 --login tomcatUser --password tomcatPassword --path /webApplication

You need managerApp for remote deployment. Dont forget to install it first of all.

Best Reagards

Answer (score -1):

you can create a empty web-project in eclipse. Paste your angular Production Build Distribution files there. Since you are using routes in angular so, in web.xml file of your eclipse web project send all type of routes requests to angular's index.html file

Comment: How exactly would you do that in web.xml?

Comment: `<servlet>
<servlet-name>angularapp</servlet-name>
<jsp-file>/index.html</jsp-file>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>angularapp</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/angularapp/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>`

This will send all url to your index file. The url pattern depends on your application-context path